# posting nested attributes from active resource frontend to active model backend

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, nested-attributes, activeresource

Hello I'm trying to post nested attributes to my backend. Posting the new model works fine as long as i don't try to include my nested model.

my form.html.erb:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@petition, :url => petitions_path, :html => {:multipart => true}, :html => {:class => 'form-horizontal' }) do |f| %>
  <%= f.simple_fields_for :userdetail_attributes do |m| %>  
          <%= m.input :anrede, :label => "Anrede", collection: ["Frau","Herr","Familie"], label_html: {class: 'span4'}, input_html: { class: 'span11  pull-right' }  %>
          <%= m.input :titel,  :label => "akadem. Grad/Bez.", label_html: {class: 'span4'}, input_html: { class: 'span11  pull-right' }%>
          <%= m.input :name, :label => "Vorname", label_html: {class: 'span4'}, input_html: { class: 'span11  pull-right' } %>
          <%= m.input :last_name, :label => "Nachname", label_html: {class: 'span4'}, input_html: { class: 'span11  pull-right' } %>
          <%= m.input :institution , :label => "Institution", label_html: {class: 'span4'}, input_html: { class: 'span11  pull-right' }%>
          <%= m.input :zip, :label => "Postleizahl", label_html: {class: 'span4'}, input_html: { class: 'span11  pull-right' } %>
          <%= m.input :city, :label => "Stadt", label_html: {class: 'span4'}, input_html: { class: 'span11  pull-right' } %>
          <%= m.input :street, :label => "Stra&szlig;e", label_html: {class: 'span4'}, input_html: { class: 'span11  pull-right' } %>
          <%= m.input :street_number, :label => "Hausnummer", label_html: {class: 'span4'}, input_html: { class: 'span11  pull-right' } %>
          <%= m.input :state, :label => "Staatsangehörigkeit", label_html: {class: 'span4'}, input_html: { class: 'span11  pull-right' } %>
          <%= m.input :telefon, :label => "Telefon", label_html: {class: 'span4'}, input_html: { class: 'span11  pull-right' } %>
          <%= m.input :fax, :label => "Fax", label_html: {class: 'span4'}, input_html: { class: 'span11  pull-right' } %>
          <%= m.input :email, :label => "E-Mail", label_html: {class: 'span4'}, input_html: { class: 'span11  pull-right' } %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.input :title, :label => "Titel der Petition", label_html: {class: 'span4'}, input_html: { class: 'span11  pull-right' }%>
  <%= f.input :ziel, :label => "Welches Ziel hat Ihre Petition?",:as => :text, label_html: {class: 'span4'}, input_html: { class: 'span11  pull-right' }%>
  ...
  <%= f.button :submit, "Petition einreichen", :class => "blue btn pull-right" %>
<% end %>
```

when i hit the button my frontend sends_out the following

```
Started POST "/petitions" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-07-11 11:58:23 +0200
Processing by PetitionsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",
  "authenticity_token"=>"u04pQ55e7qY3NYOH2PWhm5tP6maWkrq9THK5IbGX3+c=", 
  "api_petition"=>{
     "userdetail_attributes"=>{
       "anrede"=>"Frau", 
       "titel"=>"prof", 
       "name"=>"xxxx", 
       "last_name"=>"xxx", 
       "institution"=>"123", 
       "zip"=>"00000", "city"=>"Stuttgart", 
       "street"=>"klemmenstr", 
       "street_number"=>"12", 
       "state"=>"d", "telefon"=>"", "fax"=>"", 
       "email"=>"example@mail.de"}, 
     "title"=>"Sem Malesuada Consectetur Nibh Mollis", 
     "ziel"=>"Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit...",
      ... }, "commit"=>"Petition einreichen"}
```

and dies...like that

```
set authtoken --> Hdrwi8cxjijBNtyZX5MT <-- , xxx
GET http://localhost:4000/users/1.json
--> 200 OK  10102 (283.0ms)
POST http://localhost:4000/petitions.json
--> 500 Internal Server Error  8448 (102.8ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 391ms
```

my backend than receives this fancy bit

```
Started POST "/petitions.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-07-11 11:42:53 +0200
Processing by PetitionsController#create as JSON
Parameters: {"petition"=>{"akzeptiert_agb"=>"1", "gegen_was"=>"", 
   "gegen_wen"=>"", "gesetzes_aenderung"=>"", "oeffentlich"=>"1", "pstatus_id"=>1,
   "rechtsbehelfe"=>"", "title"=>"Sem Malesuada Consectetur Nibh Mollis",
   "umstand"=>"", "user_id"=>1, 

   "userdetail_attributes"=>{
     "userdetail_attributes"=>{
       "anrede"=>"Frau", "city"=>"Weimar", "email"=>"example@mail.de", 
       "fax"=>"", "institution"=>"123", "last_name"=>"name", "name"=>"name",
       "state"=>"d", "street"=>"klemmenstr", "street_number"=>"12", "telefon"=>"", 
       "titel"=>"prof", "zip"=>"99423"
     }
   }, 
   "ziel"=>"Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit..."
}}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2ms
```

i have now idea where the duplication of the userdetail attributes comes from. 
but i gues it is what leads to the following error in my backend:

```
ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error - Can't mass-assign protected attributes: userdetail_attributes:
```

my petitions_controller.rb in the frontend:

```
def new
  @petition = Api::Petition.new
  @userdetail = Userdetail.new
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # new.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @petition }
  end
end


# POST /petitions
# POST /petitions.json
def create
  @petition = Api::Petition.new(params[:api_petition])
  @petition.user_id = current_user.id
  @petition.pstatus_id = 1
  if !params[:userdetail].nil?
    @petition.userdetail = Userdetail.new(params[:userdetail])
@petition.userdetail.user_id = current_user.id
  end
  respond_to do |format|
    if @petition.save
      format.html { redirect_to user_path(current_user), notice: 'Ihre Petition wurde erfolgreich zur weiteren Prüfung überstellt.' }
    else
      format.html  { render action: "new" , notice: 'Bedauerlicherweise ist etwas schiefgelaufen, Ihre Petition wurde nicht gespeichert'}
    end
  end
end
```

my petition.rb in the backend:

```
class Petition < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :userdetail
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :userdetail #, :reject_if => proc { |attributes|   attributes['userdetail'].blank? }

  attr_accessible :title, :akzeptiert_agb, :begruendung, :gegen_was, :gegen_wen,    :gesetzes_aenderung, :oeffentlich, :rechtsbehelfe, :umstand, :ziel, :pstatus, :user, :voters, :user_id, :pdf, :can_vote, :count_users_voted, :phase, :started, :neu, :beratung, :archiv, :private_pdf, :abschlussberichts, :abschlussberichts, :status, :moderated, :moderationdate, :userdetail
```

my petitions_controller.rb in the backend

```
      # GET /petitions/new
      # GET /petitions/new.json
      def new
        @petition = Petition.new
        @userdetail = @petition.userdetail.new
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html # new.html.erb
          format.json { render json: @petition.to_json(:include => [@userdetail]) }
        end
      end

      # POST /petitions
      # POST /petitions.json
      def create
        @petition = Petition.new(params[:petition])
        #@petition.user = User.find(current_user.id) || User.find_by_authentication_token(session[:auth_token]) 
        @petition.pstatus = Pstatus.find(1)
        if params[:userdetail].nil?
            @petition.userdetail = Userdetail.new(params[:userdetail])
        end

        respond_to do |format|
          if @petition.save
            format.html { redirect_to user_path(current_user || User.find_by_authentication_token(session[:auth_token]).id ), notice: 'Ihre Petition wurde erfolgreich zur weiteren Prüfung überstellt.' }
            format.json { render json: @petition, status: :created, location: @petition }
          else
            format.html  { render action: "new" , notice: 'Irgendetwas ist gerade schiefgelaufen. Bitte wenden Sie sich an: 03643/778525.'}
            format.json { render json: @petition.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end
```

my userdetails.rb in the backend

```
class Userdetail < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :petition
  attr_accessible :anrede, :city, :email, :fax, :institution, :last_name, :name, :state, :street, :street_number, :telefon, :titel, :zip
```

Has anybody an idea how to fix this? i've been trying a lot but still can't get my head around the nesting of the userdetails_attributes. Thanks in advance and sorry for the ultra long text.

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
:userdetail_attributes
```

to

```
attr_accessible
```

or `:userdetails`, by idea should be plural.

Comment: thanks but that does not solve the problem. Have tried that before, but it had no effect.

Answer (score 0):

This following part should look different,

```
"userdetail_attributes"=>{
     "userdetail_attributes"=>{
       "anrede"=>"Frau", "city"=>"Weimar", "email"=>"example@mail.de", 
       "fax"=>"", "institution"=>"123", "last_name"=>"name", "name"=>"name",
       "state"=>"d", "street"=>"klemmenstr", "street_number"=>"12", "telefon"=>"", 
       "titel"=>"prof", "zip"=>"99423"
     }
   },
```

Like this,

```
 "userdetail_attributes"=>{
   "anrede"=>"Frau", "city"=>"Weimar", "email"=>"example@mail.de", 
   "fax"=>"", "institution"=>"123", "last_name"=>"name", "name"=>"name",
   "state"=>"d", "street"=>"klemmenstr", "street_number"=>"12", "telefon"=>"", 
   "titel"=>"prof", "zip"=>"99423"
 }
```

Comment: that is what i think too, but where does it come from? any idea?

Comment: maybe change this, <%= f.simple_fields_for :userdetail_attributes do |m| %> to <%= form_tag %> and everything inside it to input tag.